# Existence of holomorphic $f$ with $(f(z))^4=z^4+4$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

Let $\Omega=\mathbb{C}\setminus K$ where $K$ is a compact connected set containing $1+i$, $1-i$, $−1+i$, and $−1−i$. I want to prove that there exists a holomorphic function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $(f(z))^4=z^4+4$. In other words, I am trying to show $z^4+4$ has a holomorphic $4$th root on $\Omega$.

What I was able to confirm immediately is that the image of $\Omega$ under $z^4+4$ cannot contain $0$ due to the values we excluded from $\Omega$. However, it is not necessarily the case that $\Omega$ is simply connected, or even connected, so I can't invoke the Monodromy theorem. Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: A closed path $\gamma$ in $\Omega$ which encloses one of the poles of $4z^3/(z^4+4)$ will enclose all four since $K$ is connected. Using the Residue theorem you should now be able to calculate $\int_{\gamma} \frac{ 4z^3}{z^4+4}$.  If this is zero for any $\gamma$ then you should be able to to define $\log(z^4+4)$ on $\Omega$ which might be a start...

Comment: @Testcase: $\int_{\gamma} \frac{ 4z^3}{z^4+4}$ is not necessarily zero. But it is of the form $2 \pi i \cdot 4k$ for some integer $k$, and that suffices to define the function $f$ as a fourth root.

Comment: @MartinR Ah, of course. You are absolutely right. It has been to long since my complex analysis days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that $\Omega$ may not be connected, but it suffices to show that such a function $f$ exists in every connected component $U$ of $\Omega$.

Let $\{\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\omega_4 \} = \{ \pm 1 \pm i \} $ be the roots of
$$
 p(z) = z^4+4 = (z-\omega_1)(z-\omega_2)(z-\omega_3)(z-\omega_4) \, .
$$
Now let $\gamma$ be an arbitrary closed path in $U$. The [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number#Complex_analysis)
$$
 I(\gamma, a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z-a}
$$
is integer-valued and (as a function of $a$) constant in each connected component of $\Bbb C \setminus U$. Since $K$ is connected and contains all $\omega_j$ it follows that
$$
 I(\gamma, \omega_1) =  I(\gamma, \omega_2) =  I(\gamma, \omega_3) =  I(\gamma, \omega_4)\, ,
$$
so that
$$ \tag{*}
 \frac 14 \int_\gamma \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} \, dz = 2 \pi i \frac 14 \sum_{j=1}^4 I(\gamma, \omega_j) = 2 \pi i k
$$
for some integer $k$. Therefore we can fix a point $z_0 \in U$ and define $f : U \to \Bbb C$ as
$$
 f(z) = \exp \left( \frac 14 \int_{z_0}^z \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} \, dz\right) 
$$
where the integral is taken along *any* path from $z_0$ to $z$ in $U$. $(*)$ shows that this definition is independent of the choice of the integration path. Then
$$
 4 \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}
$$
in $U$, so that $f(z)^4 = Cp(z)$ with some constant $C \in \Bbb C$. Finally multiply $f$ with a suitable constant so that $f(z)^4 = p(z)$ in $U$.